# property , getter and setter function not called

Tags: oop, delphi

I think DELPHI language offers a very  clear and beautiful implementation of data encapsulation
via the property methods and clear getter and setter functions.

I want to access a class string list strlst via a getter and setter  functions.
Option #1  in the code sample works fine as expected , but option #2  calling  the
Stringlist.Commatext function does actually not work.

Is this a DELPHI bug or did  I miss something with respect to class design?

Target : fill class stringlist without creating an external Tstringlist class, just pass commatext.

```
program Project2;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, classes;

type
  TSimpleClass = class
    FStrlst: TStringList;

  private
    procedure SetStrList(const Value: TStringList);

  public
    constructor Create;

    property strlst: TStringList read FStrlst  write SetStrList;

  end;

  { TSimpleClass }

constructor TSimpleClass.Create;
begin
  inherited;

  FStrlst := TStringList.Create;

end;

procedure TSimpleClass.SetStrList(const Value: TStringList);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Writeln('class  getter / setter function is called ');
  for i := 0 to Value.Count - 1 do
  begin
    FStrlst.Add(Value[i]);
  end;

  writeln ('content of internal strlist : ' + FStrlst.CommaText )
end;

begin
  var
    aSimpleClass: TSimpleClass;
  var
    testLst: TStringList;

  try
    aSimpleClass := TSimpleClass.Create;
    try

       //   option #1  is working
      testLst:=TStringList.Create;
      testLst.CommaText := 'a,b,c';
      aSimpleClass.strlst := testLst;

     //    option #2  not working ...  this code should also call  the 
     //    setter function   
     aSimpleClass.strlst.commatext := 'd,e,f';


    finally
      aSimpleClass.Free;
    end;
    writeln ('done sample code !');
    Readln;

  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;

end.
```

cmd line window sample output

[output of this sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTBqf.png)

Comment: Option 2 should work just fine. How do you know it doesn't work? Your code is not outputting the data of `FStrlst` anywhere. Are you expecting `SetStrList()` to be called? It won't, in option 2, and that is perfectly fine. On a side note, your code is leaking `FStrlst` as `TSimpleClass` lacks a destructor to free `FStrlst`. Also, `SetStrList()` can be simplified by using `FStrlst.Assign()` or FStrlst.AddStrings()`, instead of an `Add()` loop.

Comment: pls. have a look on the console output. yes, I expect setter  is also called  in option #2, why not ? ( added  output option now for FStrlst )

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a DELPHI bug or did I miss something with respect to class design?

No, it is not a Delphi bug, but a misunderstanding on your part. You say "property, getter and setter function not called", and I understand you refer to getter and setter for `aSimpleClass.strlst`.

You have defined direct *read* access (of `FStrLst`) for `TSimpleClass.strlst`, thus there is no getter to be called when reading (as in `// option #2`), and `aSimpleClass.strlst` refers directly to `FStrLst`.

The `CommaText` property of `TStringList` has its own setter and that is called in `// option #2`

---

**Edit**

Or, if your intention is to not expose the `TStringList` at all, but only its `CommaText` property, that is OK as follows:

Make sure the `TStringList` is private, as well as a getter and setter for `CommaText`, and add the property `CommaTxt`

```
TSimpleClass
private
  FStrlst: TStringList;
  ...
  function GetCommaText: string;
  procedure SetCommaText(s: string);
public
  property CommaTxt: string read GetCommaText write SetCommaText;
  ...
end;
```

Implement the getter and setter:

```
function TSimpleClass.GetCommaText: string;
begin
  result := FStrlst.CommaText;
end;

procedure TSimpleClass.SetCommaText(s: string);
begin
  FStrLst.CommaText := s;
end;
```

Now you can access the `CommaTxt` property without exposing the `TStringList`.

Comment: I only request setter function  is  called in option #2 as well, why not....

Comment: In option #1 you are setting `aSimpleClass.strlst` to the `testLst` But in option #2 you are NOT setting the `aSimpleClass.strlst` at all, you are setting the `commatext` property.

Comment: In case I misunderstood your original post, I added the option to only provide access to the `CommaText` property if that is what you actually wanted.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your `option #2` doesn't fire the setter mthod is because in your `option #2` you are not assigning any value to your `strlst` but insteadyou are interacting with the object that is being returned by the said property.

You see when you call `aSimpleClass.strlst.commatext := 'd,e,f';` what happens is next:

1. Getter method of the `strlst` property is being called in order to return the reference to the TStringList object (the object thype that is defined by property)
2. Then the string value of `d,e,f` is assigned to the `ComaText` property that belongs to the String List whose reference was returned by your property getter method.

Now if at this time the TStringList that is part of your class would still not have been created an Access Violation would have been raised since you would be trying to access property of a non existent object.